# Trouble making a request to an API after the last 'session/end'

Tags: intern

I'm currently working on a custom reporter that sends [test results to Sauce Labs](https://saucelabs.com/docs/javascript-unit-tests-integration). The current version of the reporter can be [found here](https://gist.github.com/victornswd/5781326).

The problem with it is that it doesn't send the data after the last session. For instance, if I have 2 browsers to test on, it will only send the results for the first browser tested,  stopping before sending the second one.

The request is made at the 'session/end' topic [from the ones available](https://github.com/theintern/intern/wiki/Using-Reporters). From what I can tell the entire thing stops before the last request is made.

I made a more isolated custom reporter to show off the  problem using `setTimeout()` instead of a request. [See it here](https://gist.github.com/victornswd/5781481).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Intern process exits explicitly immediately after all sessions are complete (after `/runner/end` is published), so an asynchronous operation like that is unlikely to have enough time to complete successfully.

Intern 1.2 will contain an improvement so it will wait until any outstanding operations complete, and this will work as you expect it to.

Comment: Ok, thanks! Do you have any suggestion on when (after which topic is published) I should make async operations so they have enough time to finish?

Comment: It is not possible currently to do what you are attempting. If you want, open an enhancement request.